# gir1.2-secret-1 is installed but unrecognized by masal-extensions python package

Tags: python, linux, azure

I'm using msal-extensions which uses the gi python package. when running the code I'm getting the following error

```
Require a package "gir1.2-secret-1" which could be installed by:
    sudo apt install gir1.2-secret-1
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msal_extensions/libsecret.py", line 34, in <module>
    gi.require_version("Secret", "1")  # Would require a package gir1.2-secret-1
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 126, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Secret not available
Using Vault URI
```

but when I run

```
sudo apt list | grep gir1.2-secret-1

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use caution in scripts.

gir1.2-secret-1/bionic,now 0.18.6-1 amd64 [installed]
```

I see it's installed. I'm not sure why the python code does not recognize gir1.2-secret-1
Im using `Linux compnode03 5.4.0-1056-azure #58~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 23:14:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Any ideas?

Comment: I have same issue with Azure ML workspace, getting token failed with this